# IOS swift - objective c code migration to swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am trying to convert this code in swift.

```
- (CGPoint)targetContentOffsetForProposedContentOffset:(CGPoint)proposedContentOffset withScrollingVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity
{
    CGSize collectionViewSize = self.collectionView.bounds.size;
    CGFloat proposedContentOffsetCenterX = proposedContentOffset.x + self.collectionView.bounds.size.width * 0.5f;

    CGRect proposedRect = self.collectionView.bounds;

    // Comment out if you want the collectionview simply stop at the center of an item while scrolling freely
    // proposedRect = CGRectMake(proposedContentOffset.x, 0.0, collectionViewSize.width, collectionViewSize.height);

    UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes* candidateAttributes;
    for (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes* attributes in [self layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:proposedRect])
    {

        // == Skip comparison with non-cell items (headers and footers) == //
        if (attributes.representedElementCategory != UICollectionElementCategoryCell)
        {
            continue;
        }

        // == First time in the loop == //
        if(!candidateAttributes)
        {
            candidateAttributes = attributes;
            continue;
        }

        if (fabsf(attributes.center.x - proposedContentOffsetCenterX) < fabsf(candidateAttributes.center.x - proposedContentOffsetCenterX))
        {
            candidateAttributes = attributes;
        }
    }

    return CGPointMake(candidateAttributes.center.x - self.collectionView.bounds.size.width * 0.5f, proposedContentOffset.y);

}
```

This is what I have done so far

```
func targetContentOffsetForProposedContentOffset(proposedContentOffset:CGPoint, velocity: CGPoint) -> CGPoint
{

   let collectionViewSize:CGSize  = self.collectionView.bounds.size
   let proposedContentOffsetCenterX:CGFloat = proposedContentOffset.x + self.collectionView.bounds.size.width * 0.5

   let proposedRect:CGRect = self.collectionView.bounds
   //let candidateAttributes:UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes

   var candidateAttributes:[UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]

   /* get stuck here in for loop*/
   for (attributes: [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes] in layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:proposedRect)
   {

   }
```

[image]

Comment: What's keeping you from finishing the translation? What issues are you having?

Comment: @rmaddy I will update my question..

Comment: remove the () braces for the for loop

Comment: try   for attributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes in self.layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(proposedRect)

Comment: @Mr.T its says value of type cardviewcontroller has no member layoutAttributesForElementsInRect

Comment: where r u calling this method ? in a uicollectionview ?

Comment: its a separate function declared in class. and this is how my class initial code looks like... 


class CardsViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate,
UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

Answer (score 1):

```
override func targetContentOffset(forProposedContentOffset proposedContentOffset: CGPoint, withScrollingVelocity velocity: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {

    guard let collectionView = collectionView else {
        return .zero
    }

    let collectionViewSize = collectionView.bounds.size
    let proposedContentOffsetCenterX = proposedContentOffset.x + collectionViewSize.width / 2
    let proposedRect = CGRect(x: proposedContentOffset.x, y: 0, width: collectionViewSize.width, height: collectionViewSize.height)

    var candidateAttributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes?
    guard let layoutAttributes = layoutAttributesForElements(in: proposedRect) else {
        return .zero
    }

    for attributes in layoutAttributes {
        if attributes.representedElementCategory != UICollectionView.ElementCategory.cell {
            continue
        }

        if candidateAttributes == nil {
            candidateAttributes = attributes
            continue
        }

        guard let unwrappedCandidateAttributes = candidateAttributes else {
            return .zero
        }

        if abs(attributes.center.x - proposedContentOffsetCenterX) < abs(unwrappedCandidateAttributes.center.x - proposedContentOffsetCenterX) {
            candidateAttributes = attributes
        }
    }

    guard let unwrappedCandidateAttributes = candidateAttributes else {
        return .zero
    }

    var newProposedContentOffset = proposedContentOffset

    newProposedContentOffset.x = unwrappedCandidateAttributes.center.x - collectionView.bounds.size.width / 2
    let offset = proposedContentOffset.x - collectionView.contentOffset.x

    if (velocity.x < 0 && offset > 0) || (velocity.x > 0 && offset < 0) {
        let pageWidth = itemSize.width + minimumLineSpacing
        newProposedContentOffset.x += velocity.x > 0 ? pageWidth : -pageWidth;
    }

    return newProposedContentOffset
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is `layoutAttributesForElementsInRect` is a function and `proposedRect` is the argument of that function. You are calling that function wrongly in your code.

You need to change:

```
for (attributes: [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes] in layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:proposedRect)
```

to

```
for attributes in layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(proposedRect) as! [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]
```

Comment: getting error again. I'll upload the image and will send you link in 2 mins

Comment: @hellosheikh: Can you check with `for attributes in layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(proposedRect) as! [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]` ?

Comment: I checked now it says 
use of unresolved identifier "layoutAttributesForElementsInRect"
https://i.gyazo.com/5c07e2cee90d78579edf52fd4cff0c62.png

Comment: @hellosheikh You need to add that function, in objective C you are calling it `[self layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:proposedRect]` . So I think you need to add that method to swift as well

Answer (score 0):

This solution may help you.

```
for attributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes in self.layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(proposedRect)
{
      // ADD YOUR CODE HERE  
}
```